# Sorting errorbars with a faceted grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, errorbar

I have been struggling for a few days with this one- and cant find a slice of code to help. I have a multiple variable barplot that is faceted in ggplot2, and I finally worked it out so it looks great and conveys the data I want to show. Unfortunately, when I add the error bars to the graphic, they are all out of order and floating across the whole barplot. [(barplot example of the bane of my existence)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXR8G.png)

The Data: (thanks, I forgot about dput)

```
 > dput(plant_ag)

    structure(list(worms = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
     2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    poll_level = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Low", "Medium", "Very"), class = "factor"), 
    variable = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("biomass", "cu_seed", "pb_seed", 
    "zn_seed", "cu_buck", "pb_buck", "zn_buck", "cu_rye", "pb_rye", 
    "zn_rye"), class = "factor"), x.mean = c(0.9945992584, 4.645085363, 
    198.390869802, 58.43054462, 3795.1789451, 2883.8860731, 942.59827934, 
    1313.1415081, 707.165653286, 1529.33515045, 3811.442312, 
    6149.4490085), x.sd = c(3.14519901565836, 14.68904967299, 
    176.524518210961, 61.362498383762, 554.023490328341, 541.012498962109, 
    224.078432824798, 221.039876468939, 468.567696912978, 1021.25312103485, 
    2431.58456925777, 3004.85636935088), x.n = c(10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), se = c(0.9945992584, 
    4.645085363, 55.8219540410509, 19.4045257811089, 175.197610667382, 
    171.083173933975, 70.8598222247401, 69.8989463364104, 148.174116022446, 
    322.948593002573, 768.934556217399, 950.219016881294), 
    names = c("No EW/ Low Soil", 
    "Yes EW/ Low Soil", "No EW/ Medium Soil", "Yes EW/ Medium Soil", 
    "No EW/ Very Soil", "Yes EW/ Very Soil", "No EW/ Low Soil", 
    "Yes EW/ Low Soil", "No EW/ Medium Soil", "Yes EW/ Medium Soil", 
    "No EW/ Very Soil", "Yes EW/ Very Soil"), 
     ymin = c(0, 8.88178419700125e16, 
    142.568915760949, 39.0260188388911, 3619.98133443262, 2712.80289916603, 
    871.73845711526, 1243.24256176359, 558.991537263554, 1206.38655744743, 
    3042.5077557826, 5199.22999161871), ymax = c(1.9891985168, 
    9.290170726, 254.212823843051, 77.8350704011089, 3970.37655576738, 
    3054.96924703397, 1013.45810156474, 1383.04045443641, 855.339769308446, 
    1852.28374345257, 4580.3768682174, 7099.66802538129)), 
 .Names =   c("worms", 
"poll_level", "variable", "x.mean", "x.sd", "x.n", "se", "names", 
"ymin", "ymax"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

The code:

###########  THE GRAPH STARTS HERE

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data = plant_ag, aes(x = factor(worms), fill = factor(variable), y = x.mean,
                                 group=variable))
p <- p + geom_bar(colour="black",stat = "identity",position = position_dodge(.95))
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ poll_level)
p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=plant_ag$ymin, ymax=plant_ag$ymax), width=0.2,  stat="identity", 
                       position = position_dodge(1))
          +  facet_wrap(worms ~poll_level, ncol=4) 
p <- p + theme_bw () + theme(legend.position = c(0.15, 0.8)) + 
  ggtitle("Zinc in Plants by Soil Pollution Level") +ylab("Zn concentration in plants, ppm") + 
  xlab("Earthworm Community Present")
p <- p + scale_fill_manual(values=c('darkgray','lightblue'), 
                           name="Experimental\nPlant",
                           labels=c("Buckwheat", "Rye")) 
p
```

#########   END OF COMMAND

Any help (or commiseration) is very, very welcome! Thanks for all you folks do, it is an unbelievable help to all of us N00B's.

Comment: I can't test your code, because your data isn't reproducible (you need to paste in the output of `dput(plant_ag)` to make it easy to copy and paste your data into an R session). However, for now, does changing from `aes(ymin=plant_ag$ymin, ymax=plant_ag$ymax)` to `aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)` solve your problem?

Comment: Also, you don't need all the `p <- p + ...`. Get rid of all but the first `p` then chain each statement together with `+` and you can create the whole plot in one go. For example, `ggplot(mydata, aes(x,y)) + geom_bar() + scale_fill_manual() + etc.`. To make it easy to read, put a line break after each `+`.

Comment: I tried to get rid of the  p <- p + ...., but each one caused a  "Error: No layers in plot". simplifying to aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax) makes more sense, and is certainly more parsimonious, but again, fatal error, no plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to `aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)` in `geom_errorbar` solves the ordering problem for the errorbars. You've passed the data frame to `ggplot` in your initial call to the `ggplot` function and don't need to refer to it again. Using the data frame name inside `aes` in `geom_errorbar` overrides the ordering along the x-axis set by `ggplot`, so that the error bars are plotted based on their order in the data frame, rather than the category ordering in the plot.

Also, your code has both `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid`, but you can only use one or the other. Below is the updated plot code, with `facet_wrap` commented out. I also set the y scale, because your data has a huge value for one of the errorbars that messes up the plot.

The code below also shows how to use `+` to chain plot components together.

```
p <- ggplot(data = plant_ag, aes(x = factor(worms), fill = factor(variable), 
                                 y = x.mean, group=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(colour="black", stat="identity", position=position_dodge(.95)) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ poll_level) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), width=0.2, stat="identity",
                position = position_dodge(1)) +  
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,8000)) +
#  facet_wrap(worms ~ poll_level, ncol=4) + 
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = c(0.15, 0.8)) + 
  ggtitle("Zinc in Plants by Soil Pollution Level") +
  labs(y="Zn concentration in plants, ppm",
       x="Earthworm Community Present") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('darkgray','lightblue'), 
                    name="Experimental\nPlant",
                    labels=c("Buckwheat", "Rye"))
```

[image]

Comment: My god, that's gorgeous! Thank you very much.

Comment: I see what you did now that I have had a chance to go through it with a fine toothed comb. I thank you, and so does my dissertation!

Comment: Glad to be of service. Good luck with your dissertation!